# Print td with class

Tags: php, printing, echo

I want to add a class on my td. So i can modify it with css. But everytime i write td class right, my page stops work.

It this possible what im tryin to do? Or do i have to do it some other way?

```
$test= database_result($queryexe, 'MyDatabase');

Print("<td class="right">$test</td>\n");


td.right{
    text-align: right;"
}
```

Comment: Either escape the double quotes or change them to single quotes. `echo "hello \" <-";` or `echo "hello ' <-";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up with the " codes try the below one also add table tr td it will work fine

```
Print("<table><tr><td class='right'>$test</td></tr></table>");
```

Comment: its a 15 min delay before you can approve.

Answer (score 2):

Your Code

```
Print("<td class="right">$test</td>\n");
```

Updated Code

```
Print("<td class='right'>$test</td>\n"); // double quotes changed to single quotes
```

Also Use error reporting on top of your page to view what errors are ocouring

```
// should only be used on development servers not on production servers
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Note: Errors should only be displayed on development servers, **not** on production servers. On production servers all errors should be **logged**.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference [XHTML™ 1.0 The Extensible HyperText Markup Language (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.4) states that "Attribute values must always be quoted" - even if they are numeric, however despite the fact that the examples show them enclosed in double quotes it is perfectly acceptable to use either double-quotes or single-quotes (the example there is just an example - it's not part of the specification) and most people do use double-quotes even though the standard says you can use either.

So, you don't really have to change them to single-quotes, just put backslashes in front of them:

```
Print("<td class=\"right\">$test</td>\n");
```

...which 'escapes' them as Charlotte says so that PHP doesn't get to the quotes at the start of "right" and think that's the end of the string.